# podfile with path: cannot find podspec

Tags: swift, path, cocoapods, local

I have a project that depends on (our own) SDK framework.
In the project that uses the framework, I have the pod in the Podfile like so:

```
pod 'Our-SDK-iOS', :git => 'ssh://git@gitlab.com/myAccount/ios_sdk.git', :branch => 'development'
```

For easier development and testing of the SDK, I want to use the local files of the framework, so I do not have to commit changes to the SDK and pod update every time I want to run the app.

In the docs I found that I could use :path keyword. I implemented it like so:

```
pod 'Our-SDK-iOS', :path => '~/dev/My_Project/My_App/ios_sdk'
```

When I do this, I get an error from pod update:

> [!] No podspec found for `Our-SDK-iOS` in `~/dev/My_Project/My_App/ios_sdk`

I get no error if I add the podspec like so:

```
pod 'Our-SDK-iOS', :path => '~/dev/My_Project/My_App/ios_sdk/My-Project.podspec'
```

But does not look right and I still get no updates from my local files.

How can I make this work?
What am I doing wrong?

Kind regards,
Wouter Wessels

Comment: first of all: if your podspec is `MainbladesSDK` then `Our-SDK-iOS` should be `MainbladesSDK` as well. And yes, you specify the _path_, not the name of the podspec (so the first one is correct).

Comment: Yeah, thanks. Forgot to remove the company specific stuff in that location. ;-)
But unfortunately, when not including the podSpec, I still get the error.

Comment: The podspec has the same filename as the project. Everything works when using it with :git , but when I try to get it from the :path I get the 'No podspec found' error

Comment: But when I change the file name of the podspec file to the s.name value in that podspec file ... then it works!!!!